# Kalman filter to smooth accelerometer signals using rotation matrix

Tags: accelerometer, smoothing, kalman-filter, rotational-matrices, sensor-fusion

I have 3D accelerometer signals which are obviously noisy. I am trying to use Kalman filter to remove bias and drift from these signals. As an extra input I have rotation matrix.

I can also use a moving average filter and it will be fine but how can I use Kalaman filter to smooth these signals using rotation matrix?

Best Regards

Chintan

Comment: I am interested in this problem too. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look the documentation how to use scalar Kamlan Filter:
http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/Kalman/ScalarKalman.html

If you can run the code in Matlab and see how the scalar Kalman Filter works:
http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/Kalman/scalarkalman.m

Once you are familiar with the basic and use of scalar kalman filter then you can follow the practical implementation guide:
http://robotsforroboticists.com/kalman-filtering/

Rotation is included and the linear model is replaced by a general one. Next two filters are combined and finally the federated Kalman Filter is included:
http://campar.in.tum.de/Chair/KalmanFilter

Comment: Thank you for giving these links. I will study them and come back :)

Comment: I understood Kalman filter for Scalar case using the first two links. In fact the best description I have found so far. The 3rd link is confusing so left it. It looks like the material in the 4th link could be helpful but I need more information. In that the author uses position data along with quaternion. However, how can I apply that technique it to filter accelerometer data using rotation matrix. Thanks.